# Separate a jQuery UI datepicker into 3 separate text boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Does anyone know of an elegant way of separating the jquery-ui datepicker's input into 3 separate boxes?

By default its input is just one textbox: `DD/MM/YYYY`

I have to separate the input into 3 separate ones for day, month, and year: `DD`,  `MM`, and `YYYY`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type='text' id='fullDate' name='fulldate'>
<!-- Your other HTML fields listed above -->

$('#fullDate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var pieces = dateText.split('/');
        $('#day').val(pieces[0]);
        $('#month').val(pieces[1]);
        $('#year').val(pieces[2]);
    }
})
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/7NgpQ/

Comment: Perfect example what i was looking for Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `datepicker` function `onClose` then grab the value.

See this http://jsfiddle.net/96FPU/

This will only work if the `dateFormat` is correctly referenced by the array index, i.e. in my example, it is working from day = index 0, month = index 1, year = index 1. Also in my example i am just assigning the values to `spans'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`.datepicker('dialog')`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-dialog) method to achieve this effect.

```
function onSelect(dateText, inst) {
    var pieces = dateText.split('/');
    for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; ++i)
        $('.date:eq('+i+')').val(pieces[i]);
};

$('.date').click(function(event) {
    var d = $('.date').map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get().join('/');
    $(this).datepicker('dialog', d, onSelect, { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }, [10, 40]);
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/QHasQ/.